# Generating random number in within an inputted range

Tags: python, random

I am trying to write a piece of code that prompts the user to input a number,  and the loop will only stop if the input number matches the random generated number. The random number should be in within the range the user input.

```
import random
randNumber = random.randint(min, max)

min = int(input("Choose a minimum number range: "))
max = int(input("Choose a maximum number range: "))

while True:

  if guess > randNumber:
    print("Too big, try again")

  if guess < randNumber:
    print("Too small, try again")

  if guess == randNumber:
    print("BINGO!")
    break
```

The system keeps telling me "tuple object not callable" for my 2nd line.

Comment: You have `randNumber = random.randint(min, max)` before you even define `min` and `max`; why would you expect that to work? (even ignoring the fact that those are reserved words)

Answer (score 1):

Two problems. `min` and `max` are reserved top-level functions in Python, so you're actually passing a function object at the top. (A common practice when you want to use reserved names is to add an underscore, e.g. `min_` and `max_`.)

The other problem is `randInt` must come after you ask for user input (e.g. below a `max_ = int(input(...` line, as `min_` and `max_` are not defined.

Comment: Only a minor information: There is no need to add underscores to `min` and `max` if the `randInt` comes after the inputs. Because then, the built-in functions will simply be overwritten. But yes, it is still a good idea to rename them, of course!

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response, now I understand a lot clearer than before. However, I renamed them into `min_` and `max_`, and moved the two lines (`min_ = int(...`) to before `import`, it still shows the same error to the same line. Does it have to do with me using Google Console on Chrome to run the code?

Comment: @AliceGong The line also has it's inputs changed? e.g. `randint(min, max)` to `randint(min_, max_)`? If so, I could only guess Google Console is caching previous inputs and that's causing you problems? Feel free to paste the new code here.

Comment: @Honno here is the revised code: 
`min_ = int(input("Choose a minimum number range: "))
max_ = int(input("Choose a maximum number range: "))

import random
randNumber = random.randint(min_, max_)`
Thank you so much for your kind help

Comment: @AliceGong That looks good to me! I tested it locally, it works. I'm not familiar with Google Console, so I recommend search around on how to "refresh" your instance, or try running this code on another Python interpreter program (e.g. IDLE that comes packaged with Python downloads).